# What is the alternative to jQuery toggle() to show/hide a text?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show / hide a text extention with a certain `.class` inside a form. By selecting the rodio with the correct `.class` the extention should show. When selecting any other option within the form, the extention should hide. I tried it with the jQuery toggle() function but by clicking a second time on any of the radios the extention - regardless if selected or not - shows or hides again.

It should show only if the radio with this `.class`is selected:

> span class="span_home_2"

The toggle() I tried it is this:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        $(".span_home_2").toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="banner_location_box">
    <label class="label_head">
        <?php echo $lang ['select_page']; ?>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label class="select_page">
        <input type="radio" class="select_location" name="page_id" value="1" checked="checked"/>
        <span><?php echo $lang ['home']; ?><span class="span_home_2">(<?php echo $lang ['available_only']; ?>)</span></span>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label class="select_page">
        <input type="radio" class="select_location" name="page_id" value="2"/>
        <span><?php echo $lang ['business']; ?></span>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label class="select_page">
        <input type="radio" class="select_location" name="page_id" value="3"/>
        <span><?php echo $lang ['jobs']; ?></span>
    </label>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Just use .show() and .hide() instead of toggle.  You just have to have the logic that shows the right one based on value of the radio button.

Comment: Check radio class and then do toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bmorgan21 suggested, you want to be more specific about your logic. If you can add a show and hide class to the inputs that are supposed to show/hide the element respectively, you can do something like this:

```
$("input.show").click(function () {
    $(".span_home_2").show();
});

$("input.hide").click(function () {
    $(".span_home_2").hide();
});
```

Check out this fiddle to see if this is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/2Wsns/